# postfix - disable users to change email username after login

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a mail server with Postfix and Dovecot and users can send emails, but (after login) they can change the address and send from other `username@example.com`.

For example, `user1@example.com` login to email via IMAP/SMTP and then he change the address to `admin@example.com` and is still allowed to send mails impersonating that other user.

How can I disable this? I tried

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
```

but then `user1` cant send mail even from `user1@example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to restrict the addressess allowed in the `MAIL FROM` command based on the user, Postfix needs to know which address(es) belongs to which users. Therefore, you must use these restrictions with [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).

> `smtpd_sender_restrictions`
>
> - [`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch)
>
>   Enforces the `reject_sender_login_mismatch` restriction for
>     authenticated clients only. This feature is available in Postfix
>     version 2.1 and later.
> - [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch)
>
>   Reject the request when [`$smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) specifies an owner
>     for the `MAIL FROM` address, but the client is not (SASL) logged in as
>     that `MAIL FROM` address owner; or when the client is (SASL) logged in,
>     but the client login name doesn't own the MAIL FROM address according
>     to [`$smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).

If you are using `virtual_alias_maps` to map the addresses to local users, the format is identical for `smtpd_sender_login_maps`, and you can simply use the same file. In this example, I assume a `hash:` Berkeley DB in `/etc/postfix/virtual` (requires `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` after modifications):

```
user1@example.com user1
joe.bloggs@example.com user1
user2@example.com user2
jane.doe@example.com user2
admin@example.com root
```

With this, it's possible to utilize the same file for both purposes, and the modifications to the incoming maps will immediately affect the allowed outbound addresses, too.

- In `main.cf`:

  ```
  virtual_alias_domains = example.com
  virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  ```
- For the authenticated *submission* (on port `587`) in `master.cf` (assuming TLS & Dovecot SASL):

  ```
  submission inet n - - - - smtpd
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  ```
- Of course it's possible to use the

  ```
  smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
  ```

  directly in the `main.cf`, but I recommend using separate configuration for *submission*: It enables you to use different set of restrictions and other settings for authenticated users than for incoming mail, and it also works better e.g. with home internet connections that restricts the use of SMTP port `25`.